# Flask-admin expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Ситуация следующая. Имеется проект блога на `flask`, подключил админку по средствам `flask-admin`.
Настроил через `app.py` путем добавления:

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Tag, db.session))
```

В первом случае работа с постами идет без нареканий (создать пост, редактировать, удалить). Всё отрабатывает на ура.

Но что касаться `Tag` то вот тут и возникает проблема. Редактируются уже созданные (в ручную) теги замечательно, но вот при создании тега, после заполнения полей вылетает следующие сообщение:

```
builtins.TypeError
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1997, in create_view
    model = self.create_model(form)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 1079, in create_model
    if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 1062, in handle_view_exception
    return super(ModelView, self).handle_view_exception(exc)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 1073, in create_model
    model = self.model()
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__

  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 417, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/models.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
  File "/home/moonz/Рабочий стол/Flask/models.py", line 8, in slugify
    return re.sub(pattern, '-', s)  # Заменяет их на дефис
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Как я понимаю, на вход поступает неверный тип данных, но вот где именно проблема (а точнее в Чём) понять не могу.
Буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def slugify(s): 
    pattern = r'[^\w+]'  
    return re.sub(pattern, '-', str(s))  # Заменяет их на дефис
```

Нужно было привести значение S к строке.

Comment: и в какую строку и в какой файл нужно дописать этот код ? И что за "S" ?